# How to integrate Angular into my current Firebase node.js project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, firebase

I have a web app that I have coded in bare javascript for now and has a firebase backend. How can I add Angular to my current project to use it for MVC?

Comment: Angular 2(Actually called Angular) is not designed for MVC projects and works better as a Client + WebAPI

Comment: Firebase has good integration with Angular given they are both Google products.

Comment: I have been really confused about the whole angular and express stuff. I just want an MVC that can integrate to firebase and handle routes and I thought it would work.

Comment: Angular can talk directly to firebase with the angularfire library @joelbarbosa mentioned in the answer below. Firebase is essentially a back-end as a service meaning you dont need express or node unless you have other purpose for them.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the official library:
https://github.com/angular/angularfire2

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this but the general steps you must take are essentially:

- Download and import the required angular2 libraries
- Move html into templates as per angular2 documentation
- add JS to components, services, directives, etc to fit the required structure of an angular 2 application

Depending on your restrictions I would recommend [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) for generating the boiler plate code for you.

Comment: My current project is just a bunch of js files for each function and html files that could be the "templates"

Comment: My suggestion would be use Angular CLI to generate a new project then follow the layout of the auto generated files to move your logic and templates into the correct locations. the js functions and html pages wont change they will just be in different places to fit Angular.